# Не могу понять почему часть кода не работает

Tags: python, telegram-bot, docker, selenium-webdriver

Есть код скрипта. Он должен. Найти бота в телеграмме, проверить последнее сообщение на наличие награды или ссылки. Проверить её на работоспособность. Если нет, сделать запрос чат */visit*. Далее перейти по ссылке из первой кнопки меню. 
*Есть три вариации перехода*: 1. просто ссылка и ожидание. 2. Ссылка с нахождением на сайте определенное время. 3. Ссылка с капчей *её пропускаем*. 
**Проблема** состоит в том, что часть кода отвечающая за *открытие -> переход -> ожидание* не срабатывает в этих частях кода: 
[image: Не запускается вебдрайвер]
[image: Данная часть не работает из-за не запуска вебдрайвера]
[image: Селениум молчит]

**Сам код скрипта**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from telethon import sync, events
import requests
import json
import hashlib
import time
import re
from virus_total_apis import PublicApi as VirusTotalPublicApi
from telethon import TelegramClient
import webbrowser
import urllib.request
import os

n = 0


api_id = 
api_hash = ''

client = TelegramClient('LalkaTralnaya', api_id, api_hash)

client.start()

dlgs = client.get_dialogs()

for dlg in dlgs:
    if dlg.title == 'LTC Click Bot':
        tegmo = dlg



class RunChromeTests():
    def testMethod(self, waitin = 10, witin = 10):
        caps = ('browserName', 'chrome')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(command_executor=f'http://localhost:9515/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=caps)
        driver.get()
        time.sleep(witin + 10)
        driver.close()
        driver.quit()


while True:
    msgs = client.get_messages(tegmo, limit=1)

    for mes in msgs:
        if re.search(r'\bseconds to get your reward\b', mes.message):
            print("Найдено reward")
            str_a = str(mes.message)
            zz = str_a.replace('You must stay on the site for', '')
            qq = zz.replace('seconds to get your reward.', '')
            waitin = int(qq)
            print ("Ждать придется: ", waitin)
            client.send_message('LTC Click Bot', "/visit")
            time.sleep(3)
            msgs2 = client.get_messages(tegmo, limit=1)
            for mes2 in msgs2:
                button_data = mes2.reply_markup.rows[1].buttons[1].data
                message_id = mes2.id

                print("Перехожу по ссылке")
                time.sleep(2)
                url_rec = messages[0].reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].url
                ch = RunChromeTests()
                ch.testMethod()
                time.sleep(6)
                fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url_rec)
                mybytes = fp.read()
                mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
                fp.close()
                if re.search(r'\bSwitch to reCAPTCHA\b', mystr):
                    from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest
                    resp = client(GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(
                        'LTC Click Bot',
                        message_id,
                        data=button_data
                    ))
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("КАПЧА!")
                    os.system("pkill chromium")
                else:
                    time.sleep(waitin)
                    os.system("pkill chromium")
                    time.sleep(2)

        elif re.search(r'\bSorry\b', mes.message):
            client.send_message('LTC Click Bot', "/visit")
            time.sleep(6)
            print("Найдено Sorry")

        else:
            messages = client.get_messages('Litecoin_click_bot')
            url_rec = messages[0].reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].url
            f = open("per10.txt")
            fd = f.read()
            if fd == url_rec:
                print("Найдено повторение переменной")
                msgs2 = client.get_messages(tegmo, limit=1)
                for mes2 in msgs2:
                    button_data = mes2.reply_markup.rows[1].buttons[1].data
                    message_id = mes2.id
                    from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest
                    resp = client(GetBotCallbackAnswerRequest(
                        tegmo,
                        message_id,
                        data=button_data
                    ))
                    time.sleep(2)
            else:
                url = 'https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/url/scan'
                params = {
                    'apikey': '', 'url': url_rec}
                response = requests.post(url, data=params)
                my_file = open('per10.txt', 'w')
                my_file.write(url_rec)
                print("Новая запись в файле сделана")
                time.sleep(16)
                n = n + 1
                print("Пройдено циклов: ", n)
```

**Ошибка**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\vladm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\ptvsd_launcher.py", line 48, in <module>
    main(ptvsdArgs)
  File "c:\Users\vladm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 432,
in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\vladm\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.2.64397\pythonFiles\lib\python\old_ptvsd\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 316,
in run_file
    runpy.run_path(target, run_name='__main__')
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name,
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    _run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
  File "C:\Python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Python38-32\criptobot\scratch.py", line 96, in <module>
    url_rec = messages[0].reply_markup.rows[0].buttons[0].url
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rows'
```

Comment: А что у Вас в переменной `messages` на той строке кода, где возникает ошибка?

Comment: Должен открыть ссылку в браузере для ожидания и получения награды.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что Вы не проверяете случай, на который ругается ошибка. И поэтому пытаетесь обработать несуществующие данные.